# Add a Loading Indicator in Vue When Getting JSON in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, vue.js, axios

I am trying to add a loading indicator to my Vue app while waiting to pull the JSON object and display the list of data. I've done this before in Axios by doing something like:

```
 axios
  .get('test.com/posts.json')
  .then(response => (this.json = response.data))
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
    this.errored = true
  })
  .finally(() => this.loading = false)
```

But I am unsure how to do this same functionality when the JSON object is being grabbed in PHP like so:

```
  var json = <?php echo getBhQuery('search','JobOrder','isOpen:true','id,title,categories,dateAdded,externalCategoryID,employmentType,customText12');?>;

  json = JSON.parse(json);
  var jsonData = json.data;
```

So this is how I'm currently pulling data from my BullHorn account. I then pass the jsonData variable to my data variable in Vue.

Now this completely works to display data from the JSON object, but I am not sure the correct way to add a loading indicator while my Vue app waits to query the JSON object in PHP.

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: PHP runs on the _server_, and is completely finished and out of the picture by the time the browser sees the `var json = <?php echo getBhQuery(...)` line. What the browser gets is the _result_ of the server doing the `<?php echo` ... try viewing the page source in your browser to see what the result is.  The `getBhQuery` call happens on the _server_ before the page is even sent to the browser, so there is no wait time in the browser.

Comment: Stephen is correct, your database query has to run completely before the page loads past that point. So Vue will take longer to even start, but your data will appear instantly.  Youd have to load the job orders via an API endpoint like you did with posts .